# TSQLQuery.FieldByName().AsString -> TStringStream Corrupts Data

Tags: delphi, stream, sql-server-2008-r2, delphi-xe2

I'm using Delphi XE2.  My code pulls data from a SQL-Server 2008 R2 database.  The data returned is a `nvarchar(max)` field with 1,055,227 bytes of data.  I use the following code to save the field data to a file:

```
procedure WriteFieldToFile(FieldName: string; Query: TSQLQuery);
var
  ss: TStringStream;
begin
  ss := TStringStream.Create;
  try
    ss.WriteString(Query.FieldByName(FieldName).AsString);
    ss.Position := 0;
    ss.SaveToFile('C:\Test.txt');
  finally
    FreeAndNil(ss);
  end;
end;
```

When I inspect the file in a hex viewer, the first 524,287 bytes (exactly 1/2 meg) look correct.  The remaining bytes (524,288 to 1,055,227) are all nulls (#0), instead of the original data.

Is this the right way to save a string field from a `TSQLQuery` to a file?  I chose to use `TStringStream` because I will eventually add code to do other things to the data on the stream, which I can't do with a `TFileStream`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TStringStream` is `TEncoding`-aware in XE2, but you are not specifying any encoding in the constructor so `TEncoding.Default` will be used, meaning that any string you provide to it will internally be converted to the OS default Ansi encoding.  Make sure that encoding supports the Unicode characters you are trying to work with, or else specify a more suitable encoding, such as `TEncoding.UTF8`.

Also make sure that `AsString` is returning a valid and correct `UnicodeString` value to begin with. `TStringStream` will not save the data correctly if it is given garbage as input.  Make sure that `FieldByName()` is returning a pointer to a `TWideStringField` object and not a `TStringField` object in order to handle the database's Unicode data correctly.

Comment: I'm marking this correct because this is the correct thing to do to ensure that Unicode encoding is handled correctly.  I posted a new question though, since I found while troubleshooting that it wasn't a Unicode problem after all.  (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225450/tsqlquery-only-streams-first-1mb-of-data-correctly-for-large-strings)