# TSQLQuery only streams first 1MB of data correctly for large strings

Tags: delphi, stream, sql-server-2008-r2, delphi-xe2

(see Edit #1 with stack trace and Edit #2 with workaround at end of post)

While troubleshooting [TSQLQuery.FieldByName().AsString -> TStringStream Corrupts Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210174/tsqlquery-fieldbyname-asstring-tstringstream-corrupts-data), I found that a `TSQLQuery.FieldByName().AsBytes` will only stream exactly 1MB of `varchar(max)` data correctly.

- Using WireShark, I verified that the data is *all* being handed to the Delphi app *correctly*.
- I verified that it *always* writes out the correct number of bytes to the output file, but any bytes that exceed **exactly 1MB** are null bytes.
- Additionally, `TSQLQuery.FieldByName().AsString` and `.AsWideString` also exhibit the same behavior.

What would cause `.AsBytes` to supply the correct number of bytes to the `TFileStream`, but `null` all bytes that exceed 1MB?

### Test Case

This test case creates two output files.  `Plus14.txt` is 1MB + 14 bytes.  `Plus36.txt` is 1MB + 36 bytes.  In both cases, the bytes more than 1MB are `null` byte values.  I even tried a 16MB string.  The first 1MB of the output file was correct; the next 15MB were all `null` bytes.

### SQL Server

```
use tempdb
go
create procedure RunMe
as
  declare @s1 varchar(max), @s2 varchar(max)

  set @s1 = '0123456789ABCDEF'
  set @s2 = @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 -- 128 bytes
  set @s1 = @s2 + @s2 + @s2 + @s2 + @s2 + @s2 + @s2 + @s2 -- 1,024 bytes
  set @s2 = @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 -- 8,192 bytes
  set @s1 = @s2 + @s2 + @s2 + @s2 + @s2 + @s2 + @s2 + @s2 -- 65,536 bytes
  set @s2 = @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 -- 524,288 bytes
  set @s1 = @s2 + @s2                                     -- 1,048,576 bytes

  set @s2 = @s1 + 'this is a test'                        -- 1MB + 14 bytes
  set @s1 = @s1 + 'of the emergency broadcasting system'  -- 1MB + 36 bytes

  select @s2 as Plus14, @s1 as Plus36
go
grant execute on RunMe to public
go
```

### Delphi DFM

Default form, with this `TSQLConnection` dropped on it (and one `TButton`):

```
object SQLConnection1: TSQLConnection
  DriverName = 'MSSQL'
  GetDriverFunc = 'getSQLDriverMSSQL'
  LibraryName = 'dbxmss.dll'
  LoginPrompt = False
  Params.Strings = (
    'User_Name=user'
    'Password=password'
    'SchemaOverride=%.dbo'
    'DriverUnit=Data.DBXMSSQL'

      'DriverPackageLoader=TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,DBXCommonDriver160.' +
      'bpl'

      'DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,Borla' +
      'nd.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=16.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicK' +
      'eyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b'

      'MetaDataPackageLoader=TDBXMsSqlMetaDataCommandFactory,DbxMSSQLDr' +
      'iver160.bpl'

      'MetaDataAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXMsSqlMetaDataCommandFact' +
      'ory,Borland.Data.DbxMSSQLDriver,Version=16.0.0.0,Culture=neutral' +
      ',PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b'
    'GetDriverFunc=getSQLDriverMSSQL'
    'LibraryName=dbxmss.dll'
    'VendorLib=sqlncli10.dll'
    'VendorLibWin64=sqlncli10.dll'
    'HostName=localhost'
    'Database=tempdb'
    'MaxBlobSize=-1'
    'LocaleCode=0000'
    'IsolationLevel=ReadCommitted'
    'OSAuthentication=False'
    'PrepareSQL=True'
    'BlobSize=-1'
    'ErrorResourceFile='
    'OS Authentication=True'
    'Prepare SQL=False')
  VendorLib = 'sqlncli10.dll'
  Left = 8
  Top = 8
end
```

### Delphi PAS

The code for the `TButton.OnClick`:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var qry: TSQLQuery;

  procedure save(str: string);
  var data: TBytes; fs: TFileStream;
  begin
    fs := TFileStream.Create(Format('c:\%s.txt', [str]), fmCreate);
    try
      data := qry.FieldByName(str).AsBytes;
      if data <> nil then
        fs.WriteBuffer(data[0], Length(data));
    finally
      FreeAndNil(fs);
    end;
  end;

begin
  SQLConnection1.Open;
  qry := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    qry.MaxBlobSize := -1;
    qry.SQLConnection := SQLConnection1;
    qry.SQL.Text := 'set nocount on; exec RunMe';
    qry.Open;
    save('Plus14');
    save('Plus36');
  finally
    FreeAndNil(qry);
  end;
  SQLConnection1.Close;
end;
```

### <<< Edit #1 - Stack Trace >>>

I traced through Embarcadero's code and found the place where the `null` bytes first appear.

- `FMethodTable.FDBXRow_GetBytes`
- `Data.DBXDynalink.TDBXDynalinkByteReader.GetBytes(0,0,(...),0,1048590,True)`
- `Data.SqlExpr.TCustomSQLDataSet.GetFieldData(1,$7EC80018)`
- `Data.SqlExpr.TCustomSQLDataSet.GetFieldData(???,$7EC80018)`
- `Data.DB.TDataSet.GetFieldData($66DB18,$7EC80018,True)`
- `Data.SqlExpr.TSQLBlobStream.ReadBlobData`
- `Data.SqlExpr.TSQLBlobStream.Read((no value),1048590)`
- `System.Classes.TStream.ReadBuffer((no value),1048590)` *1MB + 14b*
- `Data.DB.TBlobField.GetAsBytes`
- `Unit1.save('Plus14')`

When `FDBXRow_GetBytes` returns, `Value: TBytes` is 1048590 bytes, with `null` values set for the last 14 bytes.

I'm not sure what to try next.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

### <<< Edit #2 - Workaround >>>

I set `SQLConnection1.MaxBlobSize := 2097152`, and now all bytes are stream to the output files correctly.  So the problem only seems to occur when `.MaxBlobSize = -1`.

The urgency to fix the issue is gone now that I found a workaround.  However, I would still like to get `-1` to work if possible since the values from my database will sometimes exceed 50 megs.  So any suggestions or help is still appreciated.

### <<< Edit #3 - Bug Report >>>

I filed a bug report with Embarcadero (QC #108475).  I will report back once the bug has been acknowledged / fixed.

### <<< Edit #4 - Escalated Bug Report >>>

I found today that using this workaround will sometimes causes a `TClientDataSet` to throw an `EOleException` with the text '**Catastrophic Failure**'.  Apparently a `TClientDataSet` prefers a `MaxBlobSize := '-1';`.  Consequently, I escalated the bug report at Embarcadero.  Hopefully they will provide a fix or a better workaround for this soon.

Comment: *What would cause TSQLQuery to supply the correct number of bytes to the TFileStream, but null all bytes that exceed 1MB?* That is to say, you've observed `WriteBuffer` to work correctly with buffers greater than 1mb and it's `AsBytes` that's returning the wrong data?

Comment: Correct.  I traced Embarcadero's code.  It's definitely in the `.AsBytes` code.  I'll add a pseudo stack trace to the question.

Comment: I think this is a bug. Please file a QC report for this with a reproducible case at http://qc.embarcadero.com

Comment: How about not using asBytes ? I wonder if TBlobField(qry.fieldByName(str)).SaveToStream(fs) has the same problem?

Comment: is the same problem occurs if you set the maxblobsize to the qry directly rather than to the sqlconnection? i.e. qry.maxblobsize := -1 ?

Comment: about the reqestlive, yes it is my mistake and delete my comment, but SO still send notification to you.

Comment: If I set the `MaxBlobSize` of the `TSQLQuery`, it throws an exception.

Comment: I have reported the bug to Embarcadero.  QC #108475.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work around the issue.  It may be possible to just set the `TSQLConnection` properties like this:

```
sqlcon.Params.Values['MaxBlobSize'] := '250000000'; // 250 megs
sqlcon.Params.Values['BlobSize'] := '-1';
```

But I set a lot more properties than these by using a `DBXRegDB` unit to setup all `TSQLConnection` components.  I don't use the IDE's property editor...  Some of the settings from the `DBXRegDB` unit may also be required for the workaround to work (I don't know for sure).  I'll include the `DBXRegDB` unit + instructions how to use it just in case.

- Add the `DBXRegDB` unit to the `.dpr` file.
- Add `DBXRegDB` to the form's `uses` clause.
- Execute the following code, passing it the `TSQLConnection` component on your form:

.

```
procedure SetupMSSqlConnection(const sqlcon: TSQLConnection; const hostname, port, maxcon, dbname, username, password: string);
begin
  sqlcon.Params.Clear;
  sqlcon.DriverName := 'MSSQL_Con';
  sqlcon.VendorLib := sqlcon.Params.Values[TDBXPropertyNames.VendorLib];
  sqlcon.LibraryName := sqlcon.Params.Values[TDBXPropertyNames.LibraryName];
  sqlcon.GetDriverFunc := sqlcon.Params.Values[TDBXPropertyNames.GetDriverFunc];

  sqlcon.Params.Values[TDBXPropertyNames.HostName] := hostname;
  sqlcon.Params.Values[TDBXPropertyNames.Port]     := port;
  sqlcon.Params.Values[TDBXPropertyNames.Database] := dbname;
  sqlcon.Params.Values[TDBXPropertyNames.UserName] := username;
  sqlcon.Params.Values[TDBXPropertyNames.Password] := password;
end;
```

Lastly, set the `TSQLQuery.MaxBlobSize` to '0', so that it will automatically copy the value from its `TSQLConnection`.

Here is the `DBXRegDB` unit, for those who want to use it.  I adapted it from something I found here: [DBX without deploying DBXDrivers.ini](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2010/11/dbx-without-deploying-dbxdrivers-ini/).  Make sure you do not set the `BlobSize` to 250 megs or you will get out of memory errors.

```
unit DBXRegDB;

interface

implementation

uses
  DBXCommon, DBXDynalinkNative, DBXMSSQL, Forms, Classes;

type
  TDBXInternalDriver = class(TDBXDynalinkDriverNative)
  public
    constructor Create(DriverDef: TDBXDriverDef); override;
  end;

  TDBXInternalProperties = class(TDBXProperties)
  public
    constructor Create(DBXContext: TDBXContext); override;
  end;

{ TDBXInternalDriver }

constructor TDBXInternalDriver.Create(DriverDef: TDBXDriverDef);
begin
  inherited Create(DriverDef, TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader);
  InitDriverProperties(TDBXInternalProperties.Create(DriverDef.FDBXContext));
end;

{ TDBXInternalProperties }

constructor TDBXInternalProperties.Create(DBXContext: TDBXContext);
begin
  inherited Create(DBXContext);

  Values[TDBXPropertyNames.SchemaOverride]         := '%.dbo';
  Values[TDBXPropertyNames.DriverUnit]             := 'DBXMSSQL';
  Values[TDBXPropertyNames.DriverPackageLoader]    := 'TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,DBXCommonDriver160.bpl';
  Values[TDBXPropertyNames.DriverAssemblyLoader]   := 'Borland.Data.TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=15.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b';
  Values[TDBXPropertyNames.MetaDataPackageLoader]  := 'TDBXMsSqlMetaDataCommandFactory,DbxMSSQLDriver160.bpl';
  Values[TDBXPropertyNames.MetaDataAssemblyLoader] := 'Borland.Data.TDBXMsSqlMetaDataCommandFactory,Borland.Data.DbxMSSQLDriver,Version=15.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b';
  Values[TDBXPropertyNames.GetDriverFunc]          := 'getSQLDriverMSSQL';
  Values[TDBXPropertyNames.LibraryName]            := 'dbxmss.dll';
  Values[TDBXPropertyNames.VendorLib]              := 'sqlncli10.dll';
  Values[TDBXPropertyNames.HostName]               := 'ServerName';
  Values[TDBXPropertyNames.Database]               := 'Database Name';
  Values[TDBXPropertyNames.MaxBlobSize]            := '250000000';
  Values['LocaleCode']                             := '0000';
  Values[TDBXPropertyNames.IsolationLevel]         := 'ReadCommitted';
  Values['OSAuthentication']                       := 'False';
  Values['PrepareSQL']                             := 'True';
  Values[TDBXPropertyNames.UserName]               := 'user';
  Values[TDBXPropertyNames.Password]               := 'password';
  Values['BlobSize']                               := '-1';
  Values[TDBXPropertyNames.ErrorResourceFile]      := '';
  Values['OS Authentication']                      := 'False';
  Values['Prepare SQL']                            := 'True';
  Values[TDBXPropertyNames.ConnectTimeout]         := '30';
end;

var
  InternalConnectionFactory: TDBXMemoryConnectionFactory;

initialization

  TDBXDriverRegistry.RegisterDriverClass('MSSQL_Con', TDBXInternalDriver);
  InternalConnectionFactory := TDBXMemoryConnectionFactory.Create;
  InternalConnectionFactory.Open;
  TDBXConnectionFactory.SetConnectionFactory(InternalConnectionFactory);

end.
```