# Deployment of the dbxdrivers.ini and dbxconnections.ini files in xe5

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-xe5, dbexpress

We have a D7 vcl app that uses dbexpress to connect to oracle (via the devart oracle driver for dbexpress). We converted this app to XE5. In D7 the dbxdrivers.ini and dbxconnections.ini files have been deployed in the same directory as the exe and the application read the them from this location without any intervention (i.e. dbexpress found automatically all the settings)

In XE5 deploying the dbxconnections.ini file doesn't work in the same way it worked in D7, in other words the application doesn't seem to use/find the two ini files when they are deployed in the same folder as the exe.

Based on my observations and reading the delphi code, I need to call the TSQLConnection.LoadParamsFromIni method and pass the dbxconnections.ini file name, otherwise the TSQLConnection object ends up reading the location from the registry: HKCU\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\12.0\DBExpress\Connection Registry File. dbexpress will read the dbxdrivers.ini from the exe directory, if it is there.

Any thoughts on this? Could you please confirm that this is how it's done?

Thanks

Update: After more testing here is the behavior that I am seeing:

- If the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\12.0\DBExpress key is not present at all, and the dbx***.ini files are deployed only in the exe folder the XE5 app uses them without having to call LoadParamsFromIni.
- If the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\12.0\DBExpress key is present with all the settings (Connection Registry File etc.) pointing to the ini files in the public folder, and the dbx***.ini files are deployed only in the exe folder, then the app doesn't read the ini files from the application folder and I need to explicitly call LoadParamsFromIni.

I think it is more reliable to call the LoadParamsFromIni than relying on the default behaviour of dbexpress.

Comment: We ran into similar issues with the DBXDrivers.ini.  We found a great article that shows how to deploy without the DBXDrivers.ini (http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2010/11/dbx-without-deploying-dbxdrivers-ini/).  We adapted it somewhat as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12312971/822072 (start reading at the paragraph "Here is the `DBXRegDB` unit").

Comment: As for DBXConnections.ini...  Do you really need it?  Are you showing your users all of the defined connections, and are you storing database name, username and passwords in DBXConnections.ini?  It seems you could setup the connection parameters at runtime and avoid using DBXConnections.ini as well.  It's hard to say though, without knowing more about how your application utilizes it.

Comment: @JamesL. I am storing only the database name and some other driver specific parameters. And of course, I am not storing the username and password. Ultimately, I want to be able to change the connection without changing the app.