# TSQLQuery Truncates Data

Tags: sql-server, database, delphi, sql-server-2008-r2, communication

I asked this question in 2012: [TSQLQuery only streams first 1MB of data correctly for large strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225450/tsqlquery-only-streams-first-1mb-of-data-correctly-for-large-strings)

I want to keep the question simple, so rather than appending more details to the other question and hoping people will look at it again, this is a new question with just the core details.

---

**Problem Summary**

> There are two settings for `TSQLConnection...MaxBobSize`.  Using `-1` loses data (a bug), and using `X MB` runs out of memory:
>
> 1. `TSQLConnection.Params.Values['MaxBlobSize'] := '-1'`, makes `TSQLQuery` look at the data length of each `var...(max)` field from the db, and allocate buffers that match each field's data length.  The first 1,048,576 bytes in each buffer are set correctly, then the remaining bytes are set to NULL (`0x00`).  Thus, **data is lost**.
> 2. `TSQLConnection.Params.Values[MaxBlobSize] := 'X MB'` makes `TSQLQuery` pre-allocates the specified `X MB` of RAM for each `var...(max)` field returned in the query.  `X MB` must be big enough for the largest `var...(max)` object.  Even at `10MB`, a query with 3 `var...(max)` fields and 100 rows will pre-allocate `3GB` of RAM to service the query, even if the actual data is much smaller.  If the machine runs out of RAM, the users see a **"Catastrophic Failure"**.

---

**Details**

In 2012, we opened an incident with Embarcadero to fix bug #1.  Their said use `X MB` instead of `-1`, which causes our users to experience condition #2.  We continued using `MaxBlobSize := -1` hoping either Embarcadero would eventuall fix #1, or that our users would never exceed the 1MB limit.

A user uploaded a 10MB image to the db, and it's likely to happen again.  When they retrieve the 10MB image, the first 1MB displays correctly, the rest of the image is missing.  The full 10MB image is correctly stored in the db.  So the user has hit bug #1.

The problem still exists in Delphi Seattle (XE10), as demonstrated by this simple test case.  I verified with WireShark that the traffic from the db includes all field data.

1. Create a new Delphi VCL Forms project.
2. Add `SQLConnection1: TSQLConnection` to the form, setup to access the database:

   - Driver=MSSQL
   - HostName=localhost
   - OSAuthentication=True
   - Database=tempdb
   - LoginPrompt=False
3. Leave the `SQLConnection1.Params['MaxBlobSize']` set to `-1`.
4. Add a `Button1: TButton` with the following `OnClick()` code:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  qry: TSQLQuery;

  procedure save(fn: string);
  var
    data: TBytes;
    fs: TFileStream;
  begin
    fs := TFileStream.Create('c:\' + fn + '.txt', fmCreate);
    try
      data := qry.FieldByName(fn).AsBytes;
      if data <> nil then
        fs.WriteBuffer(data[0], Length(data));
    finally
      FreeAndNil(fs);
    end;
  end;

begin
  SQLConnection1.Open;
  qry := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    qry.MaxBlobSize := -1;
    qry.SQLConnection := SQLConnection1;
    qry.SQL.Text := Concat(
      'declare @s1 varchar(max), @s2 varchar(max) ',

      'set @s1 = ''0123456789ABCDEF'' ',
      'set @s2 = @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1  /* 128 bytes       */ ',
      'set @s1 = @s2 + @s2 + @s2 + @s2 + @s2 + @s2 + @s2 + @s2  /* 1,024 bytes     */ ',
      'set @s2 = @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1  /* 8,192 bytes     */ ',
      'set @s1 = @s2 + @s2 + @s2 + @s2 + @s2 + @s2 + @s2 + @s2  /* 65,536 bytes    */ ',
      'set @s2 = @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1 + @s1  /* 524,288 bytes   */ ',
      'set @s1 = @s2 + @s2                                      /* 1,048,576 bytes */ ',

      'set @s2 = @s1 + ''this is a test''                       /* 1MB + 14 bytes  */ ',
      'set @s1 = @s1 + ''of the emergency broadcasting system'' /* 1MB + 36 bytes  */ ',

      'select @s2 as Plus14, @s1 as Plus36'
    );
    qry.Open;
    save('Plus14');
    save('Plus36');
  finally
    FreeAndNil(qry);
  end;
  SQLConnection1.Close;

end;
```

5. Run the application and click the button.
6. Open each file in a hex editor and look for the NULLs (`0x00`) at the end of each file.

---

**Question**

Because of the *out of memory* issues that users have seen when we use `MaxBobSize := X MB`, we need to keep `MaxBobSize := -1`.  Does anyone have any suggestions or a solution to keep `MaxBlobSize` set to `-1`, continue to use `TSQLConnection` and `TSQLQuery`, and then access all field data, even when a field exceeds 1MB?

*Another solution using native components may be okay if there's no way to use the mentioned components.*

Comment: FWIW I use the TADO... components extensively and have never had any issues with data sizes.  Store and retrieve images all the time...

Comment: I agree with @Peter.  I confess I'm not at all clear why you are using dbExpress with Sql Server - it makes you dependent on EMBA to fix their bugs and in any case the TAdo* components that come with Delphi are relatively thin wrappers around MS's tried and tested ADO layer, which has a far larger user base and consequently far fewer bugs.  I have never myself run into an ADO bug in 20 years if developing in Delphi using the TAdo* components, fwiw.

Comment: Both very good comments.  I modified the test case in the question to use ADO components, and you are right, they work without the issues mentioned.  It's time to switch to ADO.  I was using dbExpress components because we use DataSnap and were already using dbExpress with DataSnap.  Lesson learned...